# What is the result of "i%0xff"?

Tags: c

So I found this in some bluetooth code and I would like to know what it does.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(notify_data); ++i) {
    notify_data[i] = i%0xff;
}
```

The result is 0x{00 01 02 03 04 ...} but how and why?

Comment: `i % 0xFF` will produce values from `0` to `254` inclusive.  `0xFF` is hexadecimal for `255`.  `%` is the modulus operator.

Comment: Be carefull as the quality of the code taken from internet is very often low. Do not learn the language from the internet examples.

Comment: Probably it is just a bug and it should be `i % 0x100` instead. Though if you don't know what `%` does in C, it is time to read a book.

Comment: I wonder if this is why my iPhone4 doesn't work in my wife's Porsche?

Comment: I know what % operator is! but I was confused because sometimes it is used like this: %.2f but it was not the case...

Comment: @MrKovalKoval: In the %.2f context, % is not acting as an operator, it's in a quoted string. It's little more than a convention used by the printf type functions.

Comment: @P__J__ yes I know we should be carefull, but in this case the code is right! there is no problem here!

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, but I was confused with that case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is actually probably wrong.

Probably the author meant `i & 0xff` or `i % 0x100` as i % 0xff` does not make too much sense in this scope.

He wanted to save only the lowest 8 bits of the data.

The module `%` operation returns the remainder from the integer division.

Assuming `x` and `y` are integers

```
x % y = x - y * (x / y)
```

## EDIT

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(notify_data); ++i) {
    notify_data[i] = i%0xff;
}
```

This code has a very low quality. 
The issues:

1. `i` has to be `size_t` not `int`
2. `sizeof(notify_data)` it one of the most common beginner errors, as sizeof does not give the runtime size of the object. It is evaluated the compile time and as we see here on SO many beginners think that it works like `strlen` or returns the size of malloced memory block

example:

```
char x[100];
char y[200];

void printsizes(char x[])
{
     printf("sizeof(x) = %zu, sizeof(y) = %zu\n", sizeof(x), sizeof(y));
}


int main(void)
{
     printsizes(x);
}
```

3. wrong `%` use.

Comment: 8 bytes -> 8 bits.

Comment: @Bathsheba :} phone spell checker

Comment: oh, nice! you answered my question! I didnt realise that it was % operator.
+1 for you! (but someone downvoted so I cant +1)

Comment: @MrKovalKoval I've just upvoted you; you're >= 15 Get in quick!

Comment: @P__J__ Do you want to edit your answer so I accept it?
because it is not wrong!

Answer (score -1):

Since % is the operator that returns the remainder from the integer division.
It means that this code is right! 
And makes the array data equal to i up to "8 bit max value" and then repeat the cycle.
It is just a protections in order to not overflow the 8 bit value!

Thank you guys ;)

Comment: Off by 1 "i up to 255" should be "i up to 254".  Further, it is not so much a "protections in order to not overflow the 16 bit value".  It might be a "protections in order to not overflow the 8 bit value", but it does a questionable job at that.

Comment: The result of `i%0xff` (`int % int`) is -254 to 254, depending on `i`.  Never 255.

Comment: Protection not to overflow a 16 bit value should be properly written as `value & 0xFFFF`. Everything else is obfuscation.

Comment: An unsigned 8-bit integer can store values from 0 to 255 inclusive. So if you want to keep a value in the 8-bit range, you should wrap around after 255 (which you'd accomplish with `% 0x100` or `& 0xFF` as per P__J__'s answer), not after 254 (which `% 0xFF` does).

Comment: "0xff (254)" is unclear.  0xff is 255.  0xfe is 254.

Comment: ok, you are so smart guys! see every point! congratulations! you were right, I was wrong, answer edited! (was just distracted while writing)

Comment: @sepp2k Note: `some_int % 0x100` range is `[-255 ... 255]`.  The negative values not likely an issue with `int i = 0; i < sizeof(notify_data); ++i`.

Comment: 'makes the array data equal to i up to "8 bit max value"' No, it doesn't. That's what people keep trying to tell you. It makes it equal up to "8 bit max value *minus one*". That's why people keep saying that the code is wrong because the "minus one" was almost certainly not intended.

Answer (score -2):

Fills up the array with values from 0 to 0xff. If the array is larger than 0xff elements, it starts over again from 0.
Will be something like: {0, 1, ... , 254, 0, 1, .. 254, 0, 1,...} and so on.

Comment: "It keeps only the last byte of the i." That would be the case if it went to 255 instead of 254 (which, as the other answer already points out, was probably the *intent*, but not what the code actually does). As-is it'll turn 255 (whose last byte is 255) into 0, 256 (whose last byte is 0) into 1, etc.